# How to serialize async/await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Let's suppose I have this simple snippet:

```
async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("start");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("end");
    });
}
```

Obviously, everytime I push that button a new task is started even when a previous task still runs. How would I postpone any new task until all previous tasks have finished?

Some more details:

In the example above, each new task is identical to the task before. However, in the original context the sequence of tasks matters: Parameters may change (I could "simulate" it by using `DateTime.Now.Ticks`).
The tasks should be executed in the order they are "registered". Specificly, my program will  talk to a serial device. I've done this before with a background thread utilizing a `BlockingCollection`. However, this time there's a strict request/response-protocol and I'd like to use async/await if it is possible.

Possible solution:

I could imagine creating tasks and storing them in a list. But how would I execute the tasks with respect to the requirements? Or should I return to the thread-based solution I have used before?

Comment: You can still use `ConcurrentQueue` or `BlockingCollection`. Since it's a producer-consumer scenario, the latter should be the best fit.

Comment: Sure. But as I see it, I would need to wait on the queue and loop it. Would I store `Task`s or data to create a task? Would I loop the queue inside a `Task` or would the loop start a `Task`? Nevertheless, this wouldn't be much of a problem, but I was hoping that there's another way more suitable for that request/response pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could wait on a `SemaphoreSlim` asynchronously and release it once the job is done. Don't forget to configure the semaphore initialcount to `1`.

```
private static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

private async static void DoSomethingAsync()
{
     await semaphore.WaitAsync();
     try
     {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("start");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("end");
        });
     }
     finally
     {
        semaphore.Release();
     }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoSomethingAsync();
    DoSomethingAsync();
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Dont forget a Try-finally and release the semaphone in the finally clause ! Otherwise, it might lead to a quite frustrating behavior for the user if an exception is thrown in your task :)

Comment: This is exactly what I need to queue the occassional concurrent access!

Comment: You may want to move `await semaphore.WaitAsync();` outside `try`.

Comment: @Noseratio Reason for that? That depends upon, what happens if "Thread aborted" after `WaitAsync` but before entering to `try` semaphore will not be released. Both has its own pros/cons

Comment: If `await semaphore.WaitAsync()` throws for any reason, `semaphore.Release()` will still be executed. I don't think it should be, in this case.

Comment: @Noseratio It is not documented to throw exceptions. but anyway valid point, let me update my answer thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

I recommend using a `SemaphoreSlim` for synchronization. However, you want to [avoid `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) (as I explain on my blog), and also [*definitely* avoid `async void`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) (as I explain in the MSDN article).

```
private SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  await Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    await _mutex.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
      Console.WriteLine("start");
      Thread.Sleep(5000);
      Console.WriteLine("end");
    }
    finally
    {
      _mutex.Release();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for linking to your articles! Very nice! BTW, when I tried your example I had to mark the lambda expression with `async` in order to be able to compile it. Is this correct?

Comment: @StephenCleary, is there any reason we cannot just `await` the previous task, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21178958/1768303)?

Comment: @Noseratio: That approach also works. IMO the `SemaphoreSlim` code has clearer intent; it's not obvious from the `await`-previous-task code that it's important to copy the previous task.

Comment: As far as I can understand this does not guarantee the execution order if button_Click is called multiple times?  1. SemaphoreSlim does not guarantee the order the semaphore is aquired, and 2. the order the _mutex.WaitAsync() is executed on potentially separate worker threads is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Magnus: It doesn't guarantee order. It guarantees one-at-a-time.

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something, but I don't think `SemaphoreSlim` is needed for the OP's scenario. I'd do it the following way. Basically, the code just `await` the previous pending instance of the task before continuing (no exception handling for clarity):

```
// the current pending task (initially a completed stub)
Task _pendingTask = Task.FromResult<bool>(true);

async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var previousTask = _pendingTask;

    _pendingTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await previousTask;

        Console.WriteLine("start");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("end");
    });

    // the following "await" is optional, 
    // you only need it if you have other things to do 
    // inside "button_Click" when "_pendingTask" is completed
    await _pendingTask;
}
```

**[UPDATE]** To address the comment, here's a thread-safe version, when `button_Click` can be called concurrently:

```
Task _pendingTask = Task.FromResult<bool>(true);
object _pendingTaskLock = new Object();

async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task thisTask;

    lock (_pendingTaskLock)
    {
        var previousTask = _pendingTask;

        // note the "Task.Run" lambda doesn't stay in the lock
        thisTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await previousTask;

            Console.WriteLine("start");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("end");
        });

        _pendingTask = thisTask;
    }

    await thisTask;
}
```

Comment: There may be more than one "pending" task.

Comment: @JeffRSon, it works with more than one, as long they're all started with `button_Click` (or another wrapper method). This is how I tested the [initial version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21178958/1) of this: `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) button_Click(null, null);` It works because it captures the member `_pendingTask` into the local `previousTask` for use inside the `Task.Run` lambda.

Comment: Ah - okay. So you would rely on the GUI thread as a means of "synchronization".

Comment: @JeffRSon, no. This approach works equally well in a console app without any synchronization context, give it a try.

Comment: No - I mean, it's not thread-safe: if 2 threads execute `var previousTask = _pendingTask;` before a new `_pendingTask` is created. This cannot happen, of course, if all calls originate from the same thread (like GUI thread or main console app thread).

Comment: @JeffRSon, I see the point. Indeed, it is not thread-safe in terms of concurrency. The name `button_Click` suggests that wasn't the original requirement. A simple lock solves this easily as shown in my update. However, at this point I'm not sure if this approach is more efficient than using a `SemaphoreSlim`, although generally locks are cheaper.

Comment: @noseratio I realize this is an old thread, but you don't actually need a lock for a thread-safe implementation. I've personally had success doing something similar to this but using `Interlocked.Exchange<T>` to replace the old task with the new one while returning the old task as an atomic operation. Just make sure to declare the Task object as volatile.

Comment: @JonathanGray TBH I'd just use `SemaphoreSlim` these days.

Answer (score 2):

What about trying the `Dataflow.ActionBlock<T>` with the (default) max degree of parallelism of 1. This way you don't need to worry about any of the thread safety / locking concerns.

It could look something like:

```
...
var _block = new ActionBlock<bool>(async b =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("start");
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                    Console.WriteLine("end");
                });
...


async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await _block.SendAsync(true);
}
```

You could also setup the ActionBlock to receive a `Task` or `Func<Task>`, and simply run / await this input. Which would allow multiple operations to be queued and awaited from different sources.