# How to use await with click handler

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have an application that communicates with a serial port.  I am trying to make it so it doesn't freeze the UI when a series of reads are performed.  I initially used a thread, but in the long run that isn't going to work well (the code is much more complicated than what is below).  I am trying to figure out async/await, and here is what I have tried so far.

I have a click handler and related methods (details, including parameters to some of the methods, removed for simplicity) as follows:

```
private void cmdOpenModPort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // stuff
    CheckBoardsAsync();
    // stuff
}
private async void CheckBoardsAsync() {
    // Read from a serial port with different settings.
    for (byte iTryAdrs = 125; iTryAdrs <= 144; iTryAdrs++) {
        ushort[] registers = await mt.ReadRegistersChkSeeBrdAsync(iTryAdrs);
        if (registers != null) {
            // Update UI based on registers
        } else {
           // Update UI
        }
    }
}
public async Task<ushort[]> ReadRegistersChkSeeBrdAsync(byte b) {
        // can't await because the method is not async.
        return ReadRegistersChkSeeBrd(b);
}
public ushort[] ReadRegistersChkSeeBrd(byte b) {
    try {
        // read from serial port.  NOT an asynchronous method and it is
        // calling a method from a package so I cannot control this.
        return master.ReadHoldingRegisters(b);
    } catch (Exception) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work because the click handler doesn't finish until CheckBoardsAsync finishes.  I want the call to CheckBoardsAsync to be asynchronous, but that method makes a series of asynchronous calls and doesn't itself need to return anything, so there isn't a value to wait for.  Since it doesn't return anything, I can't await it.

So what is the proper way to deal with this? My understanding is that I should not use threads in this case because I am waiting for I/O, and there is hardly any computation.  So this seems like the correct approach.  Do I just fake it and have the  CheckBoardsAsync return something I don't care about?  That seems weak.

I hope I have been clear enough.

Comment: `CheckBoardsAsync` should return a `Task` instead of `void`. You should avoid `async void` unless you are adding `async` to an existing method (such as an event handler). [Async/Await Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: You're misusing `async`.  You can only use `async` if you have a method which is actually asynchronous, which you don't.  Instead, use `await Task.Run()`.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21163136/1768303 ?

Answer (score 3):

You should be getting a warning for having a `async` method that has no `await` calls in it.  Marking a method as `async` doesn't automatically make it asynchronous, it just allows the use of the `await` keyword.  Here you have CPU bound work, no IO bound work, so what you want to do is perform that work in another thread (which can be done using `Task.Run`) and then asynchronously wait on *that*.

The change is easy enough, just remove `ReadRegistersChkSeeBrdAsync` entirely and replace:

```
ushort[] registers = await mt.ReadRegistersChkSeeBrdAsync(iTryAdrs);
```

with

```
ushort[] registers = await Task.Run(() => 
    mt.ReadRegistersChkSeeBrd(iTryAdrs));
```

It would also be better practice to remove the `CheckBoardsAsync` method entirely and have the body of that method simply be the body of `cmdOpenModPort_Click`.  (Or, for that matter, just attach `CheckBoardsAsync` as the click handler.)

Comment: I do not have cpu-bound work.  ReadHoldingRegisters makes a call that reads from a serial port.  If I create a thread there (which is exactly what I was doing) I will create 20 threads, each of which will will be trying to read from the same serial port.  Also, I call the method in 3 places which is why the code is not in the click handler.

Comment: @user3229298 Then you need to do that IO asynchronously, not synchronously.  If there is a version of that method that returns a task, or takes a callback, or fires an event, or whatever, you need to be using that instead.  The use of the `async` keyword is in no way making anything asynchronous here.  If there is no asynchronous version of the IO then your best bet would be to just make the whole program synchronous from top to bottom.  Do the whole thing in a single background thread and report progress to the UI thread using something like the `Progress` class.

Comment: I guess part of the problem is that I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the async/await paradigm.  Can you point me to a good explanation of this?  What does it really mean for a method to be asynchronous?  Everything I have read says that it is NOT using another thread, but that doesn't really make sense to me--How can a single thread manage multiple execution paths?  What does a bottom-level asynchronous method do that makes it asynchronous?

Comment: Sounds like you simply need to go spend some time reading some intro tutorials, rather than asking about it on SO.  SO is a place for specific targeted questions, not tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it return `Task` (not `Task<T>`).
You can then `await` it even though it doesn't return a value.

Comment: Since nothing is ever going to be done in the continuation changing this won't do anything.

Comment: @Servy: Yes; see my comment on the question.

Comment: Or my answer.  But yes, that comment is correct.  This answer however is not the answer to the question.